# Error Domain=com.stripe.lib Code=50 "We had a problem decrypting your payment information."

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, applepay

stripe payment error **"We had a problem decrypting your payment information. Please contact apple-pay@stripe.com, and double-check you have a valid certificate at https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay/apps."**

I'm requesting like,

```
    let paymentNetworks = [PKPaymentNetwork.amex, .discover, .masterCard, .visa]

    let paymentItem = PKPaymentSummaryItem.init(label: "Test", amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: 2))

    if PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments(usingNetworks: paymentNetworks) {
        let request = PKPaymentRequest()
        request.currencyCode = "INR"
        request.countryCode = "IN"
        request.merchantIdentifier = "merchant.com.myApp"
        request.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability.capability3DS
        request.supportedNetworks = paymentNetworks
        request.paymentSummaryItems = [paymentItem]
        request.requiredShippingAddressFields = .all
        request.requiredBillingAddressFields = .all


        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) { // added this in, made no difference
            request.requiredShippingContactFields = [.emailAddress, .name, .phoneNumber, .postalAddress]
        } else {
            // we don't support before 11
        }

        let contact = PKContact()
        var name = PersonNameComponents()
        name.givenName      = "Ram"
        name.familyName     = "Kumar"
        contact.name        = name

        let address = CNMutablePostalAddress()
        address.street      = "New delhi"
        address.city        = "Ashok Nagar"
        address.state       = "Delhi"
        address.postalCode  = "110096"
        address.country     = "IN"
        contact.postalAddress = address

        request.shippingContact = contact
        request.billingContact = contact

        guard let paymentVC = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request) else {
            //displayDefaultAlert(title: "Error", message: "Unable to present Apple Pay authorization.")
            return }

        paymentVC.delegate = self
        self.present(paymentVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Checked the following from myself

1.) Create merchant-ID, Apple pay certificate and enabled Xcode.

2.) Getting .CSR from stripe and upload Processing certificate on Stripe dashboard done.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Try creating new Apple Merchant ID and make sure to create an Apple Pay Certificate using the certificate signing request you obtain from Stripe and using your new merchant ID

Comment: Thanks for your input @Niraj tried this, but no luck

Comment: and what about enabling Apple Pay from capabilities and selecting marchant ID?

Comment: It's successfully done.